# Optimizing loading speed AsyncTask

Tags: android, multithreading, android-networking

In my app I use AsyncTask to load text and images not more not less. Now sometimes it's done loading in a second and other times it can take to about 5minutes. I have used AsyncTask simply because there was a lot of information about in concerning my situation.

Now I assume the reason for faster and slower loading has to do something with my internet. However I came across the line on the android documents saying :

> AsyncTask is designed to be a helper class around Thread and Handler and does not constitute a generic threading framework. AsyncTasks should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the most.)

So am I using it right? If not what should I use and what are useful articles on it. I have been googling for network best practices but I have not found some detailed documentation explaining all options and when to use them etc.

an example of a tutorial I have used : http://android-developers.blogspot.nl/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html

Comment: and what's the problem of 5 minutes: big file or timeout due to connectivity issues?

Comment: You can speed up your request by setting the time out but if you set the timeout for the connection it will not get read the data from internet ....if you not getting the data or response it's server problem or slow of your network problem.if you need to set the timeout i will post that method

Answer (score 0):

Indeed `AsyncTask` is not designed for 5 minute long execution times, but looking at the tutorial you linked to it appears there are no timeout values set for the HTTP connection.

```
URL url = new URL("http://tpbapp.com");     
connection.setConnectTimeout(1000); // 1 sec timeout to open the connection
connection.setReadTimeout(3000); // 3 sec timeout to load the data
```

You can of course adjust these values depending on the approximate size of the data, although I've found that setting the connect timeout to greater than 1 sec for images specifically can interfere with the effectiveness of cancelling the `AsyncTask`. I have written a [blog post](http://tpbapp.com/android-development/android-asynctask-stop-running-cancel-method/) about this (scroll to bottom).

Comment: If I use this on my asynctask will the app crash if it doesn't load fast enough?

Comment: You need to wrap it with try/catch